# Не получается получить данные с кук или с сессий через гет запрос с поддомена на основной домен

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, fetch

Проблема: не получается получить данные с кук или с сессий отправляя запрос через fetch (get) с поддомена на основной домен

Код сессий в главном файле пхп

```
$some_name = session_name("logged_user");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.localhost');
session_start();
```

и формально я вижу массив кук как на поддомене так и главном домене через `var_dump($_COOKIE[$key]);` в главных файлах `index.php`

Но когда я отправлю гет запрос с **app.localhost** на
**localhost/api/v3/auth/** то тот же *var_dump($_COOKIE[$key]);* показывает пустой массив в теле ответа.

Код запроса:

```
export default async function getResource(url) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${path}/${ver}${url}`, {
      crossDomain: true,
      mode: 'cors'
    })
    return await res.json()
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы отправляя гет запрос с поддомена на основной домен видеть в ответе данные кук либо с сессий? буду благодарен за любую идею!

Comment: Флаг кук httponly точно `false`?

Comment: @IvanDudarev да, флаг в false

Comment: А попробуйте в опции `fetch` добавить `credentials: 'same-origin'` или `credentials: 'include'`